# PHP Replace With New Line

Tags: php, wordpress

On a html page I have this.

```
</h2>
<ol>
```

The page is contained in a variable called $content. I want to replace this with something else but the code doesn't work.

```
$content = str_replace("</h2><ol>", $title, $content);
```

What should i put there instead of .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this:

```
preg_replace("/<\/h2>[\s]*<ol>/", $title, $content);
```

Regardless of how you do it, it doesn't really make sense. An `<h2>` is started, but you remove that closing tag and the starting tag for the `<ol>`, which will also have a closing tag I assume? Seems like your output is going to be wrong regardless.

Answer (score 4):

`\n` is the new line character:

```
$content = str_replace("</h2>\n<ol>", $title, $content);
```

Just make sure you always use it in double quotes for PHP to recognize it as an escape sequence otherwise it will interpret it as a literal "slash" "n".

Comment: Unless the file uses windows line endings

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be (just) `\n`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your IDE / text editor, or how you're accessing your file (ie: ssh/ftp/etc.)
You may also consider using or playing around with one of the following escape characters for newline

```
"</h2>\r\n<ol>" or "</h2>\n<ol>" or even "</h2>\r<ol>"
```