# Php Replace Doesn't Work

Tags: php

This is probably really stupid.

```
 $title = <li>Something – Free Shiping</li>
```

When i use this no replace is made:

```
 $title = str_replace(' – Free Shiping','', $title);
```

Comment: you missed the quotes `$title = '<li>Something – Free Shiping</li>'`

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same/similar question? => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903529/php-replace-with-new-line

Comment: `$title = str_replace(' – Free Shiping',' – Free Shipping', $title);` should work. Are you sure you are not mixing up a hyphen with a dash?

Comment: Yes it is related but different.

Comment: @Zox then why not use the same procedure? If it works or hopefully worked for your 2 other questions, then by following the same syntax, you should be able to reach the same conclusion.

Comment: I do use but this was completelly different as the character is encoded - = &#8211;

Comment: @Zox You should have specified this in the first place then, and included that in your question. How is everyone supposed to know? I for one, never paid much attention in `mind reading classes`.

Comment: i didn't knew that firefox doesn't show html encoded things. I mean if i knew i wouldn't ask any question.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes, as the content of title should be stored as a string:

```
$title = "<li>Something – Free Shiping</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "–" i should have used

```
&#8211;
```

I checked the source code in IE and its shows

```
  &#8211;
```

instead of "–" while in FF this isn't the case.